# NameError: global name 'w' is not defined when opening file in python script?

Tags: python

When I run my code (below), it comes up with the error `NameError: global name 'w' is not defined` when it comes to opening the file.

I do not know why it is doing that because 'w' is how it writes the file, it is not a variable?

```
import random
import math

def var():
    strength = 10
    skill = 10
    dice4 = 0
    dice12 = 0
    dice_score = 0

    character_name = str(input("Please enter your characters name: "))
    skill_func(strength, skill, dice4, dice12, character_name, dice_score)

def skill_func(strength, skill, dice4, dice12, character_name, dice_score):

    print(character_name + "'s attributes are being generated! ... ")

    dice4, dice12 = random.randrange(1,4), random.randrange(1,12) 

    dice_score = dice12/dice4
    dice_score = math.floor(dice_score)
    skill = skill + dice_score

    strength_func(strength, skill, dice4, dice12, character_name, dice_score)

def strength_func(strength, skill, dice4, dice12, character_name, dice_score):
    dice4, dice12 = random.randrange(1,4), random.randrange(1,12) 

    dice_score = dice12/dice4
    dice_score = math.floor(dice_score)
    strength = strength + dice_score
    file(strength, skill, dice4, dice12, character_name)

def file(strength, skill, dice4, dice12, character_name):
    file = open("N:\Controlled Assessment - James Barham\Task Two\attributes.txt", w)
    file.writelines(character_name + " - Strength = " + str(strength) + ", Skill = " + str(skill))

var()
```

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
file = open("N:\Controlled Assessment - James Barham\Task Two\attributes.txt", w)
```

Should be this:

```
file = open("N:\Controlled Assessment - James Barham\Task Two\attributes.txt", "w")
```

Comment: It still comes up with an error, `IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'N:\\Controlled Assessment - James Barham\\Task Two\x07ttributes.txt'`

Comment: @James that's because your file location can't have \x07 inside the name.....it represents a hex value, try `r"N:\Controlled Assessment - James Barham\Task Two\attributes.txt"`